# Why this question is considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[As a male, how can I close more jewelry sales to female customers?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/as-a-male-how-can-i-close-more-jewelry-sales-to-female-customers)

I don't think this question is off-topic. Although I assume the title is making people uncomfortable, I believe it is a good question.

The question also has defined field: jewelry business, and stated the location in [united-states](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), so it's not too broad.

So, **what's wrong with this question?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I voted to close this as too-broad (it says off-topic because that's what the majority of votes were) because it's asking us how they could be a better salesman when we haven't got any form of demographic information on the customers, yes they're asking on behalf of the united-states but

- What kind of jewelry are they selling?
- What kind of age-group/class are the women going to the stall?

Say for example someone asked us, how they could sell drinks to someone because they're a bartender? Selling someone in a middle-class area cocktails is different to selling someone pints of ale in the local public house. We need more information, not only on the demographic, but it would help if they could give us **examples of what they're currently trying or going to try** and then we can give feedback on that.

A question is too broad if it elicits an array of answers. Which this question currently does. If it narrowed down to specifics, then I'm happy to vote to reopen.

Comment: *too-broad* was my choice too, as explained in the comment: *general guidelines for sales techniques to women.* WDYT Bradley?

Comment: @OldPadawan I agree I think sales techniques are on-topic but not for us to provide them but for us to scrutinize them. They should be specific scenarios.

Comment: @BradleyWilson The providing part is why I voted to close as off-topic. But if the question is edited according to your excellent suggestions, then I'll vote to reopen as well.

Comment: @BradleyWilson why do you think asking for sales technique in a specific scenario is off-topic/too broad? We provide advice on specific scenario, why not this one?